# Is There A Way to Insert Multiple Tabs in a Print Line

Tags: python

I've been web searching for this answer for a week or so and I'm not sure I'm either asking the right question or there is no way to do what I want, so here I am.

I understand that '\t' represents a single tab space in a line.

But is there a simpler way to represent say for example, three tabs, between words besides inserting '\t\t\t' in the print line?

I'm looking for something more eloquent, if possible.
TIA. - Bruce

Comment: Assign it to a variable if you'd like and then multiply that. `TAB = '\t'` `TAB * 3` (or just multiply `\t`)

Comment: There are python packages for printing tabular output, if that is what you are after. I am not well versed in any of these from personal experience. An example is tabulate: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-create-tables-in-python-2eaea447d8fd Another example is prettytable https://ptable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

Comment: Actually doing literally what you are asking is hard to answer accurately - inserting tabs in a string generically is best done exactly with \t\t\t - if you want to separate words with tabs instead of spaces you might try splitting the string on space, and then joining it again with three tabs, but it is hard to say without knowing exactly what you are after - there might be better solutions for specific cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you can easily multiply a string by the repetition number to obtain a new string:

```py
print("\t" * 3 + "my text")
[output]:           my text
```

If you use this print multiple time, you can create your own print function:

```py
def custom_print(value, *a**kwars):
    print("\t" * 3, value, *args, **kwars)

custom_print("text1", "text2")
[output]:            text1 text2
```